# How to read pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf

I am working on a java project that needs to read a pdf file.

I know it is possible using some external libraries like **itext**.

But is it possible to read a pdf file using java inbuild features without using any external library?

Comment: Yes it's possible. But it's going to be a lot of work...

Comment: why don't you want to use external libraries?

Comment: Java has no native support for the pdf format. You would have to implement the required logic to decode and process the binary format.

Comment: Basically InputStream and some definitive guide on how pdf stores it's information in bytes will do it. But I suggest using iText or Apache PDFBox, they are opensource.

Comment: @davioooh it is the requirement

Comment: @Hassan Please let me know that work around in java

Comment: @RAVITEJA It's not a work-around. You have to parse the file from scratch. This is not a trivial matter. Have a look at this Wikipedia article to get an idea of the format's structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Technical_overview. It would probably be easier to somehow get around the no-library requirement.

Comment: Maybe if you can explain _why_ you have a no-library requirement, people can advise you better?

Comment: Requirement is to provide the tool with core java without using any external libraries so that the client can use it just by installing jre.

Comment: @Hassan Please can you explain me about You have to parse the file from scratch

Comment: @RAVITEJA If you include an external library in your program, your client doesn't have to intall it. It would be included in your final JAR file. As far as the JVM is concerned, you wrote that code, it doesn't know the difference. Whatever code you or I write to parse the pdf files isn't going to be as good as the code from itext. Just use that code, that's what they wrote it for.

Comment: The Affero licence for iText might be incompatible with your use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For reading pdf file from java gone through Apache PDFBOX. This PDFBOX allows creation of new PDF documents, manipulation of existing documents and the ability to extract content from documents. Apache PDFBox also includes several command line utilities.

Comment: Thank you fariyad. It is helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

You can to recover the text of a PDF file with Apache PDFBox. In maven project pom.xml, we must add dependence

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The code:

```
try {
    DLFileEntry fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(folder.getGroupId(), folder.getFolderId(), fileName);
    File file = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFile(themeDisplay.getUserId(), fileEntry.getFileEntryId(), fileEntry.getVersion(), true);
    PDDocument pddDocument=PDDocument.load(file);
    PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To read/create a PDF, see the documentation:

https://pdfbox.apache.org/