# How to Read PDF file in Java?

Tags: java, pdf

I have received pdf file from the server.I want to open that pdf file in read only.There is no edit option.so I cant use File operations.

which library is best to read pdf file?

How to read pdf file in java?

Comment: Use either iText or PDFBox. Googling your title leads to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830583/how-to-read-pdf-file-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PDFBOX](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html) or [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

I use below code while using PDFBOX.

```
try
    {
    document = PDDocument.load(f);
    document.getClass();
if( document.isEncrypted() )
{
try
{
document.decrypt( "" );
}
catch( InvalidPasswordException e )
{
System.err.println( "Error: Document is encrypted with a password." );
System.exit( 1 );
}
}

PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String st = stripper.getText(document);

System.out.println(st);
```